# Is the series expression of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$ valid for any real $x$?

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...\tag{1}$$

$$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...\tag{2}$$

Are $(1)$ & $(2)$ valid for any real $x$?

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: No, the first is valid only for $x\in (-1,1]$, and thus the second is only for $x\in [-1,1)$. Treating the case of the endpoints is a little tricky though (well, not really; it follows from Abel's theorem on power series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric series converges whenever $|x| < 1$, which is given by:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + \ldots
\end{align*}

Due to the properties of power series (precisely, uniform convergence), we can integrate both sides:
\begin{align*}
-\ln(1 - x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1 - y} = x + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{x^{4}}{4} + \ldots
\end{align*}

whence we conclude the proposed series converges whenever $x\in(-1,1)$.

You may also apply your favorite convergence test if you want.

**EDIT**

When $x = -1$, then we obtain the numerical series:
\begin{align*}
I = -1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} - \ldots
\end{align*}

Such series converges due to the Leibniz test.

On the other hand, when we set $x = 1$, the obtained series diverges because it is the harmonic series. In order to conclude so, you can prove that it is not convergent because it is not a Cauchy sequence, apply the Integral test or the Condensation test if you want.

Comment: So, $x$ can be any real number whose magnitude is less than 1?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic That's the point.

Comment: You didn't talk about ln(1+x).

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic You can substitute $x$ by $-x$ and the desired relation holds.